# Rails Devise gem User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to Rails and have used Devise gem for User authentication etc. On my app I would also like to track additional User attributes such as First Name, Last Name, etc..

What is the best way to be able to manage the additional User information. Do I add the columns required to the User model created by the Devise gem OR do I create a brand new model/table to hold this information with the appropriate associations between the two models?

thanking in advance.

regards

Comment: See http://www.jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html for an example of adding fields to devise.

Comment: Is this a better option then creating a new Model to hold the additional info and associating it?

Answer (score 1):

if you just have a application without a user profile it would be better to add first name and last name to user `rails g migration add_first_name_and_last_name_to_users first_name:string last_name:string` and in your application controller add this

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name)}
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :current_password, :password , :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name)}
end
```

however if you have a app with profile it can be better to create a Profile model that have first name and last name and others parameters such as user summary etc